# Elementor Fatal error: Class 'Elementor\Widget_Base' not found

Tags: plugin-development

I'm trying to create basic widget in Elementor. When following the developer docs to create a new widget, the following error is thrown:

Fatal error: Class 'Elementor\Widget_Base' not found

Here is my code (mostly copied from official docs)

**Main plugin extension class:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Deo Elementor Extension
 * Description: Custom Elementor extension.
 * Plugin URI:  https://elementor.com/
 * Version:     1.0.0
 * Author:      DeoThemes
 * Author URI:  https://elementor.com/
 * Text Domain: deo-elementor-extension
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

/**
 * Main Elementor Test Extension Class
 *
 * The main class that initiates and runs the plugin.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
final class Elementor_Test_Extension {

    /**
     * Plugin Version
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @var string The plugin version.
     */
    const VERSION = '1.0.0';

    /**
     * Minimum Elementor Version
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @var string Minimum Elementor version required to run the plugin.
     */
    const MINIMUM_ELEMENTOR_VERSION = '2.0.0';

    /**
     * Minimum PHP Version
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @var string Minimum PHP version required to run the plugin.
     */
    const MINIMUM_PHP_VERSION = '7.0';

    /**
     * Instance
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @access private
     * @static
     *
     * @var Elementor_Test_Extension The single instance of the class.
     */
    private static $_instance = null;

    /**
     * Instance
     *
     * Ensures only one instance of the class is loaded or can be loaded.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @access public
     * @static
     *
     * @return Elementor_Test_Extension An instance of the class.
     */
    public static function instance() {

        if ( is_null( self::$_instance ) ) {
      self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;

    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @access public
     */
    public function __construct() {

        add_action( 'init', [ $this, 'i18n' ] );
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', [ $this, 'init' ] );

    }

    /**
     * Load Textdomain
     *
     * Load plugin localization files.
     *
     * Fired by `init` action hook.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @access public
     */
    public function i18n() {

        load_plugin_textdomain( 'elementor-test-extension' );

    }

    /**
     * Initialize the plugin
     *
     * Load the plugin only after Elementor (and other plugins) are loaded.
     * Checks for basic plugin requirements, if one check fail don't continue,
     * if all check have passed load the files required to run the plugin.
     *
     * Fired by `plugins_loaded` action hook.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @access public
     */
    public function init() {

        // Check if Elementor installed and activated
        if ( ! did_action( 'elementor/loaded' ) ) {
            add_action( 'admin_notices', [ $this, 'admin_notice_missing_main_plugin' ] );
            return;
        }

        // Check for required Elementor version
        if ( ! version_compare( ELEMENTOR_VERSION, self::MINIMUM_ELEMENTOR_VERSION, '>=' ) ) {
            add_action( 'admin_notices', [ $this, 'admin_notice_minimum_elementor_version' ] );
            return;
        }

        // Check for required PHP version
        if ( version_compare( PHP_VERSION, self::MINIMUM_PHP_VERSION, '<' ) ) {
            add_action( 'admin_notices', [ $this, 'admin_notice_minimum_php_version' ] );
            return;
        }

        // Include plugin files
    $this->includes();

    // Register widgets
     add_action( 'elementor/widgets/widgets_registered', [ $this, 'register_widgets' ] );

    }

    /**
     * Admin notice
     *
     * Warning when the site doesn't have Elementor installed or activated.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @access public
     */
    public function admin_notice_missing_main_plugin() {

        if ( isset( $_GET['activate'] ) ) unset( $_GET['activate'] );

        $message = sprintf(
            /* translators: 1: Plugin name 2: Elementor */
            esc_html__( '"%1$s" requires "%2$s" to be installed and activated.', 'elementor-test-extension' ),
            '<strong>' . esc_html__( 'Elementor Test Extension', 'elementor-test-extension' ) . '</strong>',
            '<strong>' . esc_html__( 'Elementor', 'elementor-test-extension' ) . '</strong>'
        );

        printf( '<div class="notice notice-warning is-dismissible"><p>%1$s</p></div>', $message );

    }

    /**
     * Admin notice
     *
     * Warning when the site doesn't have a minimum required Elementor version.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @access public
     */
    public function admin_notice_minimum_elementor_version() {

        if ( isset( $_GET['activate'] ) ) unset( $_GET['activate'] );

        $message = sprintf(
            /* translators: 1: Plugin name 2: Elementor 3: Required Elementor version */
            esc_html__( '"%1$s" requires "%2$s" version %3$s or greater.', 'elementor-test-extension' ),
            '<strong>' . esc_html__( 'Elementor Test Extension', 'elementor-test-extension' ) . '</strong>',
            '<strong>' . esc_html__( 'Elementor', 'elementor-test-extension' ) . '</strong>',
             self::MINIMUM_ELEMENTOR_VERSION
        );

        printf( '<div class="notice notice-warning is-dismissible"><p>%1$s</p></div>', $message );

    }

    /**
     * Admin notice
     *
     * Warning when the site doesn't have a minimum required PHP version.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @access public
     */
    public function admin_notice_minimum_php_version() {

        if ( isset( $_GET['activate'] ) ) unset( $_GET['activate'] );

        $message = sprintf(
            /* translators: 1: Plugin name 2: PHP 3: Required PHP version */
            esc_html__( '"%1$s" requires "%2$s" version %3$s or greater.', 'elementor-test-extension' ),
            '<strong>' . esc_html__( 'Elementor Test Extension', 'elementor-test-extension' ) . '</strong>',
            '<strong>' . esc_html__( 'PHP', 'elementor-test-extension' ) . '</strong>',
             self::MINIMUM_PHP_VERSION
        );

        printf( '<div class="notice notice-warning is-dismissible"><p>%1$s</p></div>', $message );

    }

    /**
     * Include Files
     *
     * Load required plugin core files.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @access public
     */
    public function includes() {

        require_once( __DIR__ . '/widgets/test-widget.php' );
        //require_once( __DIR__ . '/controls/test-control.php' );

  }


  public function register_widgets() {

    \Elementor\Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager->register_widget_type( new \Elementor_oEmbed_Widget() );

  }


}

Elementor_Test_Extension::instance();
```

**Test widget class:**

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

class Elementor_oEmbed_Widget extends \Elementor\Widget_Base {

    /**
     * Get widget name.
     *
     * Retrieve oEmbed widget name.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access public
     *
     * @return string Widget name.
     */
    public function get_name() {
        return 'oembed';
    }

    /**
     * Get widget title.
     *
     * Retrieve oEmbed widget title.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access public
     *
     * @return string Widget title.
     */
    public function get_title() {
        return __( 'oEmbed', 'plugin-name' );
    }

    /**
     * Get widget icon.
     *
     * Retrieve oEmbed widget icon.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access public
     *
     * @return string Widget icon.
     */
    public function get_icon() {
        return 'fa fa-code';
    }

    /**
     * Get widget categories.
     *
     * Retrieve the list of categories the oEmbed widget belongs to.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access public
     *
     * @return array Widget categories.
     */
    public function get_categories() {
        return [ 'general' ];
    }

    /**
     * Register oEmbed widget controls.
     *
     * Adds different input fields to allow the user to change and customize the widget settings.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access protected
     */
    protected function _register_controls() {

        $this->start_controls_section(
            'content_section',
            [
                'label' => __( 'Content', 'plugin-name' ),
                'tab' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TAB_CONTENT,
            ]
        );

        $this->add_control(
            'url',
            [
                'label' => __( 'URL to embed', 'plugin-name' ),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TEXT,
                'input_type' => 'url',
                'placeholder' => __( 'https://your-link.com', 'plugin-name' ),
            ]
        );

        $this->end_controls_section();

    }

    /**
     * Render oEmbed widget output on the frontend.
     *
     * Written in PHP and used to generate the final HTML.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @access protected
     */
    protected function render() {

        $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();

        $html = wp_oembed_get( $settings['url'] );

        echo '<div class="oembed-elementor-widget">';

        echo ( $html ) ? $html : $settings['url'];

        echo '</div>';

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem.  Take $this->includes(); out of the init method, and put it into the register_widgets method:

```
public function init() {

   ...

   // Include plugin files
   // $this->includes(); // <-- remove this

}

public function register_widgets() {

    $this->includes(); // <- put it here
    \Elementor\Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager->register_widget_type( new \Elementor_oEmbed_Widget() );

}
```

Comment: Many thanks Frank! That's exactly what I discovered yesterday. I've created separated method and put $this->includes there and it worked. I published the issue on Elementor Github repostory. Don't know why others downvote this post, there is obviously something wrong with documentation code or with the core. But Github repository is disabled now due to the DMCA :) Anyway your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

go to `/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/ReservoirLabs_v2`

and open `functions.php` file

and comment `require( get_template_directory()`

Comment: Wouldn't that be editing the core ReservoirLabs_v2 theme files and thus resulting in not being able to update the core without losing changes, at best, and potentially breaking other features at worst?  Please also try and include an explanation as to why your answer works and what it is attempting to accomplish.